# Pass variable from jquery to code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#Button1").click(function () {
                var list = [];
                var a= $("#TextBox1").val();
                var b= $("#TextBox2").val();
                var count = a* b;
                list.push('test');
                for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                   var item = $("#DropDownList_" + i + "_").find(":selected").text();
                   list.splice(i, 0, item);
                   console.log(list.join());
                   alert(list[i]);
                 }              
             });
       });
     </script>
```

Hello guys first time at the stack! I have this jquery code that get all choices of dropdown list and store it in array.
I want pass this array to c# so I can store the values in DB, please help.

Comment: I am really clueless why you are doing so but you can use `jQuery ajax` to send this array to code behind.

Comment: @RahulSingh please show me how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this using jQuery ajax:-

```
var dataToSend = { "Data": list};
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: "Default.aspx/SaveData",
           data: JSON.stringify(dataToSend),
           success: function (msg) {
                //success data if any 
           },
           error: function (msg) { //handle error here }
     });
```

Add this method in your page behind (Default.aspx.cs):-

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveData(string[] Data)
{
     //Save data to DB
}
```

Comment: should I put the $.ajax in $("#Button1").click(function () to perform the passing?

Comment: Also, when I'm trying at .cs to put using System.Web.Services.WebMethod   I got an error.

Comment: I already put it in with the button click and I think it works because it displays the error msg function [ error: function (msg) ] .

Comment: using System.Web.Services.WebMethod,the namespace doesn't exist.